# Impossible to retrieve my OIDC id_token in my Angular2 web application

Tags: angular, apache, redirect, http-headers, openid-connect

Here is the situation:
I have a configuration of OIDC that redirects to `{MY_APP_URI}/app/redirect` after a successful authentication (via the parameter `OIDCRedirectURI`). Note that my application (Angular2) runs on Apache 2.4.
The problem is that I need to retrieve my access token on my application side.

This token is stored only once in the response headers of the page `{MY_APP_URI}/app/redirect` while redirecting (302 status code). My application can't access this page because it is protected by the oidc module.

Is there any way that I can either:

- Store this token - via an apache configuration - in a cookie ?

- My angular application can read and intercept the page `{MY_APP_URI}/app/redirect`
- Transfer the headers on the redirection to my application home page in order to get the needed data from there ?

Comment: Which header is the token stored in? Typically it will be in the Location header, after the '?' or '#' symbol in the URL. When redirected, you will be able to read the token from the URL query string or fragment using JavaScript.

Comment: No it's not stored in the Location header, it's stored in the form data response headers. As the Location header, it has no arguments.